# executing ngFor in html make the id of object in array of objects undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-ng-if

i am developing a mobile application using the ionic framework, i have an api call that gets transaction data and i have to list the transaction in my html template:

the data returned by the api:

```
[
    {
        amount1:"100",
        buyer_email:null,
        buyer_name:"test",
        confirms_needed:2,
        created_at:"2018-07-09 07:56:33",
        id:8,
        invoice:null,
        currency1: "USD"
    },
    {
        amount1:"100",
        buyer_email:null,
        buyer_name:"test",
        confirms_needed:2,
        created_at:"2018-07-10 04:36:33",
        id:6,
        invoice:null,
        currency1: "USD"
    }
]
```

the typescript code that make the api call :

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.transactionProvider.getTransactions()
    .subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.transactions = data;
      console.log(this.transactions);
    },error=>{
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

and i am initializing transactions by just typing transactions under export class.

This is how i am looping on the transaction data.

```
<div class="width-100p  fl-left box-shadow   border-radius-10 padd-tp-bt-10 mg-tp-20" *ngFor="let transaction of transactions">
    <div (click)="saveTransactionClick(transaction)">
        <img width="20" src="assets/imgs/currencies/icons/{{transaction.currency1}}.png">
        <div class="fl-left mg-l-10">
            <div class="f-size-12 width-100p fl-left">{{transaction.currency1}} text: {{transaction.id}} :tet</div>
            <div class="f-size-10 width-100p fl-left gray">{{transaction.created_at | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</div>
            <div class="f-size-10 width-100p fl-left gray">{{transaction.created_at | date: 'hh:mm:ss'}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is when i `console.log(this.transactions)` the id is undefined but the rest of the data is correct: ammount, buyer_name ...

if i remove the ngFor from the html the ids are back to normal.

I have no idea why this might happen and i do not know how to fix it 
Thanks

---

**Update**

**The error was using ngIf the wrong way**

in my html i had an wrong ngif that i was not aware of 
`*ngIf="transaction.id = clickedTransactionId"` when changed to `*ngIf="transaction.id == clickedTransactionId`" it worked well

thanks

Comment: post your ```*ngfor``` part of code.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: currency1 in transaction does not exist. Your JSON does not have commas.

Comment: no this is a small sample of the json 
the data is too big to put it here and currency exist, i'll fix it.

Comment: you are still missing a comma between `}` and `{`. Your code is working to me. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nr97qp?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: @George Did you tried null check?

Comment: guys it was my mistake 
i had an ngif at the end of my html code that was assigning the id, `*ngIf="transaction.id = clickedTransactionId"` 
when changed to `*ngIf="transaction.id == clickedTransactionId"`
it worked well 
thanks to you all and sorry for the silly mistake 
i wasnt aware of the ngif

Comment: Answer your post and accept, to change the status of this post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an ngif a while ago that was assigning the id instead of checking it for value

`*ngIf="transaction.id = clickedTransactionId"`

Changed it to

`*ngIf="transaction.id == clickedTransactionId"`

and everything worked as expected, Thank you all.